# I am using Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop with single boot, I don't know what happened and I paste the error message here

Tags: boot

I am using Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop with single boot. I don't know what happened, and I paste the error message here.

```
[ 1.1800501 integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 /dev/numeOn1p2: clean, 502523/31227904 files, 15065420/124895488 blocks  
[ 6.5166201 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol _IZ.ETMD1, AE_N  
OT FOUND (20220331/psargs-330) I 6.516745)   
ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.IETM. OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
```

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Now iam using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, i reboot it .but i want know why is error cause. for future tell me how handle it.